# Hashes of Array in Perl : traversal and deletion

Tags: perl, hash

how can i delete an element from the following hash of arrays;

```
%HoA = (
    flintstones    => [ {day=>'19'}, {day=>'21'}, {day=>'22'} ],
    jetsons        => [ {day=>'29'}, {day=>'23'}, {day=>'25'} ],
    simpsons       => [ {day=>'26'}, {day=>'33'}, {day=>'27'} ]
);
```

Like how can i delete e.g `{day=>'21'}` from `flintstones` and make the result look like;

```
%HoA = (
    flintstones    => [ {day=>'19'}, {day=>'22'} ],
    jetsons        => [ {day=>'29'}, {day=>'23'}, {day=>'25'} ],
    simpsons       => [ {day=>'26'}, {day=>'33'}, {day=>'27'} ]
);
```

I have tried using  Hash = (); but that results in `undef,` in place of the element that i delete

Answer (score 10):

If you know that you want to remove the `[1]` element from the flintstones array, you can use `splice` directly:

```
splice @{$HoA{flintstones}}, 1, 1;
```

If you simply know that you want to remove elements having day = 21, use `grep` either in this way:

```
$HoA{flintstones} = [ grep { $_->{day} != 21 } @{$HoA{flintstones}} ];
```

Or in this better way, as suggested by Sean's answer:

```
@{$HoA{flintstones}} = grep { $_->{day} != 21 } @{$HoA{flintstones}};
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@{ $HoA{flintstones} } = grep { $$_{day} != 21 } @{ $HoA{flintstones} };
```

This has the advantage over just assigning a fresh arrayref to `$HoA{flintstones}` that existing references to `$HoA{flintstones}` (if any) will all continue to refer to the array in `%HoA`.

Or, more readably:

```
my $flintstones = $HoA{flintstones};
@$flintstones = grep { $$_{day} != 21 } @$flintstones;
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over `keys %HoA`, apply [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) on each of the arrays (you will have to unreference them with `@{$HoA{$key}}`), store references to the results back in `$HoA{$key}`.

Answer (score 0):

> Use delete function to delete specific element from the hash .

delete  $HoA{flintstones}->[1];

Comment: it gives "NOT an Array reference"

Answer (score 0):

delete ${${$HoA{flintstones}}[1]}{day};